# What-if analysis using a fitted regression with ARMA errors

Tags: r, regression, arima

Using linear regression as an equation for prediction is straightforward with,

$$ Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i. $$

Once the betas are estimated I can insert different values of $X$ to use as a what-if analysis for different scenarios.

But trying to do the same with ARIMA models is proving difficult to translate. For example with an ARIMA(2,1,1) model, how do I create an equation where I can try out different scenarios to see how the projection changes?

Below I have the output for a projection of sales based on past sales and extra regressors. I see that a unit change in `poc0_3_PER` results in a `135.2229` change in sales. But how do I account for the moving average and auto-regression components?

```
arima(ts.count, order=c(2,1,1), xreg=df.back[3:4])

Call:
arima(x = ts.count, order = c(2, 1, 1), xreg = df.back[3:4])

Coefficients:
          ar1     ar2     ma1  poc0_3_PER
      -0.4569  0.2458  0.9455    135.2229
```

I have `ar1` and `ar2` estimates along with `ma1` and the extra regressors. How do I convert this into a working equation wherein I can try out different scenarios for the extra regressors to see how the prediction is affected?

I'm hoping that the solution is not an equation like [this post here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-2-1-0-x-0-2-2-period-12?rq=1). I do have SARIMA models at times with orders like `SARIMA(2,0,1)(1,0,1)[12]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y$ denote `ts.count` and $x$ denote `poc0_3_PER`. Then

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\Delta y_t &= 135.2229 x_t + u_t \\
u_t &= -0.4569 u_{t-1} + 0.2458 u_{t-2} + \varepsilon_t + 0.9455 \varepsilon_{t-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

For example, if you have $y_{t-1}$, $x_t$, $u_{t-1}$, $u_{t-2}$ and $\varepsilon_{t-1}$, the point prediction of $y_t$ will be

$$ \hat y_t = y_{t-1} + 135.2229 x_t - 0.4569 u_{t-1} + 0.2458 u_{t-2} + 0 + 0.9455 \varepsilon_{t-1} $$ (as $\hat\varepsilon_t=0$).

If you do not have $u_{t-1}$ and $u_{t-2}$ directly, you can get them as $u_{t-1} = \Delta y_{t-1} - 135.2229 x_{t-1}$ and $u_{t-2} = \Delta y_{t-2} - 135.2229 x_{t-2}$, respectively. Meanwhile, $\varepsilon_t$ can be found as the model residual by applying `resid(modelname)` where `modelname` is the fitted ARIMA model object.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @RichardHardy. What is $u$ in this case? For example: $y_{t-1}=5000$, and $x_t = 5$ How do I determine the $u_{t-1}$, $u_{t-2}$ parameters?

Comment: Where can I read more on $u$?

Comment: I have edited the post, so there is a little bit on how $u$ is obtained from a fitted model. I looked at Rob J. Hyndman's blog post ["The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/) when composing the answer. A broader consideration of the model could be found in Hyndman & Athanasopoulos ["Forecasting: Principles and Practice"](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1).