# What does this mean? Can you explain it to me in laymans term?

Tags: forecasting, arima, intuition

[image: ?]

How to interpret this? What does the ARIMA(0,0,0)(0,1,0)[12] means in laymans term?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ARIMA%280%2C0%2C0%29%280%2C1%2C0%29%5B12%5D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a mathematical equation for ARIMA (2,1,0) x (0,2,2) period 12](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/how-do-i-write-a-mathematical-equation-for-arima-2-1-0-x-0-2-2-period-12). See also the related questions in the panel on the right of this thread and of the one I linked to.